# Tar - Error Loading Shared Libraries - CentOS

Tags: centos, tar

I am trying to `untar` a file with extension `.tar.gz` on `CentOS 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64`.

However, I get following error when using command `tar -xvf bandwidth-1.5.1.tar.gz`

> tar: error while loading shared libraries: libRzlib.so.1: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or directory

I have the `zlib` installed and even after searing online, can't get solution for this issue.

Any suggestions on how I can solve this?

Comment: [This may be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480764/linux-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had installed `TERR` on this system earlier and had following path in `/etc/ld.so.conf`:

> /opt/TIBCO/terrde44/lib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

For some reason, I commented above path from `/etc/ld.so.conf`. To my surprise this lead to above `tar` issue. I realized this after I searched library `libRzlib.so.1` on my system and found that it's located in `TERR`'s lib folder.

Now I can use `tar`. I don't understand why a `linux` utility will depend on another application library for its working.